# How to assign values from dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
tokens_file_input = apply_stopwording(word_tokenize(str(file_input)),3)  

in_both = [] #this is the words that are in both the dictionary keys, and in the file_input dataset
dictionary_keys = lexicon_dictionary.keys()

for token in tokens_file_input:
    if token in dictionary_keys:
        in_both.append(token)
```

I have a list of words that are both in my file, and in the dictionary.. How can I now assign the values from the dictionary to those words?

Thanks!

This is what the dictionary looks like:

```
{'able': 0.25,
 'unable': -0.125,
 'dorsal': 0.0,
 'abaxial': 0.0,
 'ventral': 0.0,
 'adaxial': 0.0,
 'acroscopic': 0.0,
 'basiscopic': 0.0,
 'abducting': 0.0,
 'abducent': 0.0,
 'adductive': 0.0,
 'adducting': 0.0,
 'adducent': 0.0,
 'nascent': 0.0,
 'emerging': 0.0,
 'emergent': -0.125,
 'dissilient': 0.25,
 'parturient': 0.0,
 'dying': -0.625,
 'moribund': -0.75,
 'last': 0.0,
 'abridged': 0.0,
  ...
  }
```

This is what my output looks like now:

```
['think', 'seem', 'able', 'make', 'correct', 'understand', 'words', 'think', 'appropriate', 'confuse', ... ]
```

I would like it have the output also include the value that is associated with that particular word. So maybe a new dictionary which has these values plus the keys from the lexicon dictionary.

I can't really put my original document as it has sensitive information... thanks.

I would like my output to look something like:

```
{'think': 0.32 'seem': .23 'able': 0.25, 'make': .23, 'correct': .12, 'understand': .23, 'words': .12}
```

Comment: Does your code work?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre that just gives me the values.. i wanted to try and get something more like: {able: 0.25, make: .43 ...}

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? What this means is maybe ~10 items in your input dictionary and the *exact output* you want from your logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of declaring `in_both` as a list declare it as an empty dictionary and add values.

```
tokens_file_input = apply_stopwording(word_tokenize(str(file_input)),3)  

in_both = {} #this is the words that are in both the dictionary keys, and in the file_input dataset
dictionary_keys = lexicon_dictionary.keys()

for token in tokens_file_input:
    if token in dictionary_keys:
        in_both[token]=lexicon_dictionary[token]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a comprehension list:

```
in_both = {key:val for key,val in lexicon_dictionary.items() if key in tokens_file_input}
```